# ExtendedSocketException encountered when calling TcpClient.ConnectAsync() from a UWP app

Tags: uwp, system.net.sockets

When calling TcpClient.ConnectAsync(), a `ExtendedSocketException` is encountered with the message "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions". However, connecting to the same TCP endpoint with a regular .NET app, from the same machine, and same VS solution, succeeds (thus eliminating any concern over firewall or other network issues).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by adding the "Private Networks" capability to the app package:
[image]